# Wanted to know common practice for determining which tests to be executed & which to be skipped?

Tags: testng

We are using Testng with RC. Would want to know a common/practical/generally used way to determine which tests to be run & not run.

Take to scenario - In one test suite I have 3 modules - A, B & C. In each of the modules, there are 5 - 6 tests. The tests have been created & run fine. But as my tests would increase I may want to skip a few of tests in either of the module. I want to only run A3, A5, B1, B2, C3,C4 & C5. How would I implement these settings? 
Ways that I could think of -

1. Should these settings(tests to be run) be done from excel file. Say
   the sheet has a list of all the test case(title only) & only ones
   that are flagged "yes" should be executed.
2. Should these settings be configured from the testng.xml itself? If yes then how? I am aware that I can create groups & do that. But is that how is done?

The overall idea is not to touch the tests or play with the annotations to miss the tests.
If 1 is the answer then how would the excel file communicate with the Testng to tell it what test to be run & which one are not to be run? Or if there is another way(surely there would be) to acheive this.

Please provide some inputs on the issue, let me know if something is not clear.

Regards
Tahir

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into using groups?

Comment: yes, i am aware that I can group my tests & then run selected groups from testng.xml.  The groups has to be added on my test method or class. Would like to know if that's how others implement in my given scenario. Or are there other ways to do it.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to define different execution lists:

1. As [Cedric recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9294231/wanted-to-know-common-practice-for-determining-which-tests-to-be-executed-whic/9297770#9297770), define groups that suite your execution needs and execute specific group or collection of groups that you need at the time.
2. Create different `testng.xml` file for each execution need. This option shouldn't be just used instead of creating groups, but could be used when you need some specific configuration for test/class/method defined, like specific listener or set of properties different for each `<test>`.
3. You can implement your own [method interceptor](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#methodinterceptors). In my experience, this is a good solution if you have a lot of legacy tests (especially with existing annotations), that you don't want to (or even can't) touch, but you still need way to make a decision on the selection at the execution time.
4. I should probably mention [running TestNG programmatically](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng-programmatically), since it is a possible approach. However, I am not really familiar with this one, so I won't recommend it.